# last li being split down the middle when using css columns

Tags: html, css, html-lists, multiple-columns

So I'm using css columns in a full page navigation I'm building. This is because the nav can be dynamically added to, so need to allow for space for more nav items.

However, where some nav items titles are long enough to fall onto two lines, the last li seems to be cut in half. It looks as if it's halfway through a portal.

Screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvxtA.jpg

I seem to have exhausted all possible column styles, and nothing thus far has worked.

Code is below:

html:

```
<div class="category-headers">
    <ul id="category_header_content">
        <li><a data-dismiss="modal" href="/waterproofing-applications/test-6/" class="">Template 6 Test Long Title Page</a></li>
        <li><a data-dismiss="modal" href="/waterproofing-applications/test-6/" class="">Template 6 Test Page</a></li>
        ...
        <li><a data-dismiss="modal" href="/waterproofing-applications/test-6/" class="">Template 6 Test Long Title Page</a></li>
        <li><a data-dismiss="modal" href="/waterproofing-applications/test-6/" class="">Template 6 Test Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.category-headers{
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100vh - 185px);
  padding: 0 50px;
  top: 110px;
  width: 40%;
  left: 60%;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  ul{
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    li{
      list-style: none;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      a{
         color: $text-light-blue;
         font-size: 20px;
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow :) please input your code into your question rather than using a screenshot, otherwise we do not know how to assist in your issue.

Comment: I've now added my code. thanks!

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but commenting out `display:inline-block` solves the issue. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RegjEj)